# Duplicate Symbole in xCode, But no duplicate exist

Tags: xcode, debugging, duplicate-symbol

**The Problem**
Xcode (Version 4.6.1 (4H512)) is complaining a duplicate symbole problem.

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PacksStoreHelper in:
>       /Users/shannoga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/English_Club-cyrjamihpabtvtdkvctjwyidupuo/Build/Intermediates/English Club.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/English Club.build/Objects-normal/i386/PacksStoreViewController.o
>       /Users/shannoga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/English_Club-cyrjamihpabtvtdkvctjwyidupuo/Build/Intermediates/English Club.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/English Club.build/Objects-normal/i386/PacksStoreHelper.o
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_PacksStoreHelper in:
>       /Users/shannoga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/English_Club-cyrjamihpabtvtdkvctjwyidupuo/Build/Intermediates/English Club.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/English Club.build/Objects-normal/i386/PacksStoreViewController.o
>       /Users/shannoga/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/English_Club-cyrjamihpabtvtdkvctjwyidupuo/Build/Intermediates/English Club.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/English Club.build/Objects-normal/i386/PacksStoreHelper.o
>   ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Usually I go to the Target `Build Pases` -> `Compile Sources` and look for the duplicate.

This time as you can see there is no duplication there:
[image: Compile Sources]

**What I tried and some wacky stuff :**

1. Deleting Derived Data.
2. Removing the project and restarted the mac.
3. I even tried to delete the so called "duplicate" files and here it got even more wacky - The target successfully builded and there was no warning even that the files were not visible in the file navigator. After the build the app works fine but one of the controllers is not visible.
4. I `Alt+Clicked` the import statements of the duplicate files in other files that uses them and it gets me onto a "Zombie" file with all the code inside. But I can not see where xCode get the file from.

What the hell could it be?

I am about to shoot myself. Please save me.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution?

Comment: No, I had to recreate the project.